# How to check has VLC.MediaElement seek completed?

Tags: uwp, event-handling, mediaelement, libvlc, seek

I didn't find any event handlers like `SeekCompleted` build in `VLC.MediaElement`. I check if seek has completed using following dirty code. Is there any better way to do this?

```
//SET SEEK POSITION
VLCMediaPlayerElement.Position = Position;

//WAIT UNTIL SEEK HAS BEEN COMPLETED
while (VLCMediaPlayerElement.Position == Position)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a 3rd party library, not from Microsoft or VLC team, you should provide the download link to the library, or nuget package name, or GitHub repository.

Comment: [VLC.MediaElement](https://github.com/kakone/VLC.MediaElement) uses [libvlcx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libVLCX/) which is the VideoLAN official C++/CX libvlc wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get one good solution. It is possible to use `RegisterPropertyChangedCallback`to create handler. Like following:

```
var Token = vlcMediaElement.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(VLC.MediaElement.PositionProperty, PositionHasChanged_void);
```

In `void PositionHasChanged_void()` I can check if position is correct. If so I can unregister handler like this:

```
vlcMediaElement.UnregisterPropertyChangedCallback(VLC.MediaElement.PositionProperty,Token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Buffering` and/or `SeekableChanged` events from https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-winrt/blob/master/modules/libvlcppcx/EventManagerCX.hpp if you can access those.